# passing an argument through assert(loadfile(play.lua))(argument) doesnt assign anything to arg[1] inside play.lua

Tags: lua, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a script `play.lua` that uses a filename as an argument in order to play the notes written on each line of the file. Im trying to write a script `jukebox.lua` that will run `play.lua` with various arguments based on an input, but the global argument table wont hold the arguments i assign using `loadfile`

play.lua (section that errors)

```
local name = "file " .. arg[1]

for line in io.lines(arg[1]) do
--[[note playing code]]--
print(".")
  end
```

My first attempt looked like this, but would return an error saying `arg[1]` was the nil value when trying to assign `arg[1]` to a variable in `play.lua`

jukebox.lua

```
assert(loadfile("play.lua"))("file1")
```

Then I tried assigning `arg[1]` in `jukebox.lua`

```
arg[1] = "file1"
assert(loadfile("play.lua")
```

this ran the code with no errors, but using
`lua jukebox.lua` would play nothing and print nothing while `lua play.lua file1` would play the file as normal and would `print(".")` for each line in the file file1.
I also tried `dofile` and `require` with similar results

My question: Is writing `assert(loadfile("play.lua"))("file1")` in the script not identical to writing `lua play.lua file1` in the console?

Edit: I made a new script play1.lua with the entirety of the code provided below.

play.lua

```
local name = "file " .. arg[1]

for line in io.lines(arg[1]) do
print(".")
  end
```

jukebox.lua

```
arg[1] = "file1"
assert(loadfile("play.lua"))()
```

Comment: Replace `local name = "file " .. arg[1]` with `local arg = {...}; local name = "file " .. arg[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lua standalone interpreter both puts the command-line arguments into the global `arg` and passes them to the chunk that it calls. In other words, when you do `lua play.lua file1`, something like this happens:

```
arg = {"file1"}
assert(loadfile("play.lua"))("file1")
```

And the script can then use either the varargs syntax `...` or the global `arg` to access them. Your `play.lua` uses the latter. `assert(loadfile("play.lua"))("file1")` gives an error because it's only setting up the former. `assert(loadfile("play.lua"))` isn't doing anything because it's only loading the chunk, not actually calling it. Adding an extra set of empty parentheses, i.e., `assert(loadfile("play.lua")()`, will fix that, and in combination with you setting `arg[1]`, will make it work.

Comment: after adding the () and setting `arg[1] = "file1"`, im still getting arg[1] is a nil value when using jukebox.lua

Comment: @LucRiffault Are you sure you didn't accidentally declare a new `arg` that's `local`? Can you edit your question to include the exact content of both of your files during your latest attempt?

Comment: edited, even made a new script with nothing else but the above code to make sure `arg` or `...` were not used anywhere else.

Comment: I think I found the problem and it appears to be with my interpreter. Im not sure how the console im using differs from using lua on linux, but using your code worked perfectly when i tried it on linux. Ill probably take my question to a forum more specific to my application. Regardless, I learned a lot more about what is happening to arg[] when running a script and i greatly appreciate your explanations.

Comment: @LucRiffault Huh, that is strange. What is the platform that you're using?